# Google Place API Fetch List of Restaurants with food type

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I am developing an iPhone application in which i want to fetch the list of Restaurants with user choice food types. For Example Indian, Iranian and Chinese and many more.
As per documentation Food is depreciated. How can i accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types), you still have almost 4 months left to use the type food in your request. Because it is noted here that the types finance, food, general_contractor, grocery_or_supermarket, health, place_of_worship will still continue to be supported until February 16, 2017.

I think the alternative way that you can use with this after the deprecation is use the `type=restaurant` and use the optional parameter keyword.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=chinese&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```